# Magento 2 icon font position problem (navigation menu)

Tags: magento2, navigation, topmenu, position, fonts

Magento2 - I am trying to put some icons in my navigation menu, I want them to be on top of the subcategory name but this is what I have until now:

[image: problem with navigation menu]

This is my code for the first item, I have it in **>Magento Theme>web>css>source>_module.less:**

```
.navigation li:nth-child(1){
.lib-icon-font(
@_icon-font-content: @icon-phones2,
@_icon-font-color: @color-gray-omnie1,
@_icon-font-color-hover: @color-gray-omnie1,
@_icon-font-color-active: @color-gray-omnie1,
@_icon-font-size: @tamanho-iconos,
@_icon-font-vertical-align: top,
@_icon-font-margin: 0 0 0 30px
);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the link?